# No ADDRESS_RESOLUTION agent available

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to use Unetstack to develop an underwater sensor network of 400 sensor nodes. The nodes are assigned the addresses according to their names. Everything works well until node 255. According to the log file I get this:

> startup: No ADDRESS_RESOLUTION available.

Is there a limit for the number of nodes I can use in the network? If not, then I will be grateful if you help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

A unet node's address is represented using 1 byte. Since the number of nodes will be less than 256 in most practical deployments, using 1 byte addresses helps reduces the packet overheads. This caps the maximum number of nodes in a single network to 256 (2^8).

Comment: Do note that the roadmap for the upcoming version of UnetStack includes an option to switch between 8-bit and 16-bit network addresses to allow larger networks.